# Magento ver. 1.9.2.1 new order missing

Tags: orders, order-status, order-email, order-grid

Recently I transfer my hosting to Godaddy. They did a site migration for me. However, after the migration, there is a weird situation that

1. when a new order comes in, I can see it when I first logged in. But after a while, the order just disappear. I couldn't find it even in my database.
2. I have configured the email setting. I can receive and sent email properly. But I cannot receive the copy of new order email

my site is www.vehicode.com

Can Someone please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For new orders that are disappearing - that's very strange and should not be happening.  I'd make sure that you don't have any additional extensions that are automatically processing orders, or moving them into a different order status after they come in.

I would recommend checking your admin area to view ALL orders instead of just ones that are pending.

I would also recommend that you check in with your payment processor to make sure that payment is going through properly, and that you have orders in your payment system.  That will allow you to know / ensure that your orders are actually making it through.

For the transactional emails not showing up (order confirmation emails), you need to do a couple of things:
 - Make sure Magento cron is configured and running properly.  If Magento cron isn't running, the system will not send out confirmation emails.
- With Godaddy hosting, you can't just send emails via SendMail and have them go through - you will need to use their custom outbound email settings.   You'll want to set your system to use the relay-hosting.secureserver.net system.  More details are here: http://www.satollo.net/godaddy-using-smtp-external-server-on-shared-hosting

- Also, make sure that the email address you are using is the same domain as your website; a yahoo or gmail address won't work.
- And make sure you have an SPF record in your DNS zone file to give permission to the site to snd emails on your behalf.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using SMTP Pro extension for my email. Could you guide me how to set it up with godaddy? Thank you